# Erlang - invalid/wrong date

Tags: date, erlang

How can I validate a date in Erlang?
What happens is that, for example, the date 2018-02-31 is a "valid date" in the sense that I can work with it. When I insert this date on a table (field date) it converts itself to 2018-03-03 (2018-02-28 + 3 days).
What I want is a way to let me know that the original date of my example (2018-02-31) is indeed an invalid date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use calendar module

```
calendar:valid_date(Date) -> boolean().
calendar:valid_date(Year, Month, Date) -> boolean().
```

You will receive true or false

The detailed information and correct input format is here [Erlang Calendar Module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html#type-date)

Comment: Thank you. I did not see your answer before posting my own. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this works just fine for me:
calendar:valid_date()

Thank you.